# QGIS on Mac WKT import problem

Tags: qgis, mac, well-known-text, import

QGIS 1.8.0 Mac OSX 10.6.8
These problems seem to be specific to Mac, as two Windows users don't have the problem.

Import a file as a vector:
TEST.CSV

```
id;wkt  
1;"POLYGON((10 10,20 20,20 30,20 10))"  
...
```

The features import with correct values, individual points can be edited, and the layer saved as a shape file. But, no feature can be selected that was imported this way, so they can't be moved. New features added manually to the same layer can be selected and moved normally.

Probably related, only wkt-created features fully contained within the view are shown, wkt-features that have even a small bit outside the view vanish entirely. However, features added manually to the layer behave normally by showing the portion in the view. Layer editing capabilities are normal (full).

Has anyone suggestions as to a workaround for this? I'm hoping to migrate a dozen maps with 10,000 or so features from an old package that only exports true CSV:
x1,y1
x2,y2
...
I can script-edit this format to the above WKT, or similar text format. I don't have an app for .dbf so haven't been able to look there for any difference between WKT imports and QGIS-created features.

Comment: I can only confirm that a CSV with above mentioned line works in QGIS on Win7. I've no access to Mac.

Comment: Thanks underdark - that confirms what I understood from another user. Might you know of any QGIS tool that would show details of all the files QGIS uses for shapefiles?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Vector file formats? Or the actual parts of a Shapefile: shp, prj, dbf, ...?

Comment: the latter - I'm gessing dbf is the most likely to show a difference, shp second.

Comment: I've put the files on my website: http://johnsankey.ca/QGISWKT.ZIP in case anyone on Windows can read them.

Comment: Sorry but why are we talking Shp now when I thought we're trying to debug WKT problems.

Comment: All 3 problems continue unchanged when the WKT is saved as a shape file, the WKT layer deleted, then the shape file added. Therefore whatever is going wrong must be reflected there. That might help us to figure out what's going wrong and maybe allow us to fix it.

Comment: Your WKT file does not work nor Linux nor Mac OS X.The problems is 1) with the comma separator that also  split the WKT string, with semicolon separator, it is ok and 2) lot of errors of geometry.

Comment: This is nuts, but ... when I paste my polygons into QuickWKT and hit OK, it pastes them into QGIS, one layer for each feature. It yells about errors, but it does it. I can select the feature in the QuickWKT layer and paste it where I want and it's fully editable! I'm going to have to wait for a better method to work before I do most of my local maps, but I need one of them enough to take the time to individually copy/paste features this way.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a problem of MAC OS X or Windows, but a problem of your WKT geometry which is not valid.
You can check it with the extension [QuickWKT](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickWKT/):

[image]

and the result is:

[image]

or independently of QGIS in Python with the module Shapely

```py
from shapely.wkt import loads
wkt = loads('POLYGON((10 10,20 20,20 30,20 10))')
Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
"Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input."
 shapely.geos.ReadingError: Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input.
```

Why, because **a polygon must be closed**:

> POLYGON((10 10,20 20,20 30,20 10,**10 10**)), for example

and the result is

[image]

and in Python with the module Shapely:

```py
wkt = loads('POLYGON((10 10,20 20,20 30,20 10,10 10))')
list(wkt.exterior.coords)
[(10.0, 10.0), (20.0, 20.0), (20.0, 30.0), (20.0, 10.0), (10.0, 10.0)]
```

The expression is valid for a LINESTRING(10 10,20 20,20 30,20 10)

[image]

Comment: Hi gene, I tried duplicating the start point at the end - no change.

Comment: Also, how do I install QuickWKT to my QGIS on a Mac? The download is a directory full of things and no directions on the README as to how to install it, also no mention of Mac/Linux/Windows, which has me worried.

Comment: I should add that QGIS seems to understand both cases: it created the same polygon in both cases, and didn't make a duplicate node in the 2nd case.

Comment: QuickWKT is a plugin and to install a plugin, you must use the Plugin/install plugin menu. As it is in Python, it n 'is no matter if it's Windows, Mac or Linux

Comment: Got it - I didn't realize that QGIS won't look locally for plugins, only on-line. QuickWKT approves the WKT with the closing point added, but QGIS still has the problems I describe.

Comment: @johnsankey Try removing the double quotes from your CSV data.

Comment: Very strange because I don't have this problem in MAC OS X (10.6.8 also) with QGIS 1.8 or QGIS master. Try editing the file with the Plain Geometry Editor plugin which is the reverse of QuickWKT, editing the geometry in WKT format.

Comment: my test file is id,wkt
1,"POLYGON((10 10,20 20,20 30,20 10,10 10))"
2,"POLYGON((30 10,30 40,50 40,50 10,30 10))"

Comment: Now I've found that adding a point to one of the WKT-created polygons solves both problems for just that polygon. I've installed the editor you mention, but it doesn't seem to do anything when clicked - no file input request or anything like that...

Comment: It fixed the problem only for the first feature I tried. Just tried a second, more complex one, and it didn't :( I've also found that id only works on the added features and on the first feature I edited; it does nothing when the other wkt-created features are clicked. More clues for an expert to check, but no use for me yet.

Comment: @snorfalorpagus that makes it no longer CSV and import fails - the WKT has to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

For everybody, the **Plain Geometry Editor plug-in** in action, clicking on a point of one of the geometries in **Edit mode**:

[image]

and you can change the WKT chain

[image]

But if I try with your original geometry

[image]